# How to setup local syslog-ng in docker container of CentOS 7?

Tags: docker, centos7

I want to isolate a testing environment in docker, I did that on CentOS 6 [How to let syslog workable in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973554/how-to-let-syslog-workable-in-docker)

In CentOS 7, the syslog-ng's configuration is different, when I run

```
/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslogd.pid
```

It appears the following error message, but there is no proc/kmsg in config files.

```
syslog-ng: Error setting capabilities, capability management disabled; error='Operation not permitted' 
Error opening file for reading; filename='/proc/kmsg', error='Operation not permitted (1)'
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM centos
RUN yum update --exclude=systemd -y \
  && yum install -y yum-plugin-ovl \
  && yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y syslog-ng syslog-ng-libdbi
```

The test process:

```
docker build -t t1 .
docker run --rm -i -t t1 /bin/bash
```

In container, run following commands

```
# check config, no keyword like proc/kmsg
cd /etc/syslog-ng
grep -r -E 'proc|kmsg'

/usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslogd.pid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf from

```
source s_sys {
  system();
  internal();
};
```

to

```
source s_sys {
  unix-stream("/dev/log");
  internal();
};
```

It still show error message, but running instead of exit

```
syslog-ng: Error setting capabilities, capability management disabled; error='Operation not permitted'
```

To solve this, just run with `--no-caps` option

```
/usr/sbin/syslog-ng --no-caps -F -p /var/run/syslogd.pid
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you mind explaining a little bit?